# why doesnt this program give run time error?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
   int i,j,k;
   i=1;j=2;k=3;
   int *p =&k;
   *(p-1)=0;
   printf("%d%d%d",i,j,k);
   getch();
}
```

the output is 1 2 3.

Comment: First of all, why would you it give a runtime error?

Comment: memory access violation may be.

Comment: Why do you think it should? p points to k on the stack, p-1 points to one integer before k on your stack. It isn't necessary an access violation. It is a dangerous and undefined behavior though.

Comment: even if you replace the line  *(p-1)=0; by  *(p-1000)=0; I get the same output 123

Comment: Try `*(p+1)=0`. I'd expect it to print 103.

Comment: yes the output is 103. That answers the above question but for *(p-1) shouldnt i get a runtime error?

Comment: You're writing to the yet empty and unused stack space with `p-1`. Nothing of importance is there at this time, so why should you get an error? It is undefined behaviour, and not crashing is well defined UB as well.

Comment: Ok,I get it now. The stack grows downwards. Thanks

Comment: Try writing 0s upward until you hit the return address of the main call. Then you should get your crash. ;)

Comment: @Ashok 'Stack growing' ain't defined in C. This is clear UB, unicorns may fly or god servant may appear. No need to theoreticize what went wrong imho.

Comment: @Ashok: The stack grows downwards on your particular implementation; it's not guaranteed to behave that way on all platforms.  Don't assume this will behave the same way everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior, the pointer arithmetics you're doing is invalid.

You can only do pointer arithmetics on pointers that actually point into an array, and the result of the addition or subtraction must still point inside the array (or one past its end, if you don't intend to dereference it).

So anything could happen, the compiler can generate whatever code it feels like for that code.

Comment: I tried this code because int i;
    float *p= (float*) &i;
    *p=100.00;
    printf("%d",i); gives no run time error. So should I expect unexpected behaviour for the above code?

Comment: That's invalid code too, you're violating aliasing rules. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98340/what-are-the-common-undefined-unspecified-behavior-for-c-that-you-run-into

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to refer to `p-1` after assigning it `&k` this is an invalid pointer for you, and the behavior of using it is undefined.

Comment: Well, really you are allowed to refer to any address. The unknown is what will happen when you do. So you should not. It's a fine point but maybe the one the OP is asking about. It's not Java.

Comment: Actually, according to the standard you are not allowed to use it at all. not even assign it to another variable, and such action results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I defer to your knowlege. When I did the most C there was no standard. I think his compiler is letting him do it. That's what I mean by allowed. It's a bad thing to do whatever you call it.

Comment: OK, when I said allowed - I meant that the behavior is defined. I obviously used the wrong term. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

A run-time error only occurs if your stray pointer hits something that raises that error, such as some protected memory or a location that will later become a divisor in some calculation (0), for example.