# gcc optimization ignores program line

Tags: c, optimization, volatile

Programming the Attiny1634, I try to reuse ram space. Doing so I reused `my_array[0]` first element to send a u8 value to `my_function` requiring a pointer to uint8_t, but whatever I did, the function got the wrong value. Strangely when I printed the value before calling `my_function` everything works as intended. My suspicion is that setting the array value is ignored by the compiler when I do not use it and using its pointer does not count as using it.

```
uint8_t my_array[2];
...
my_array[0] = some_value;

// Serial0_print_U8(my_array[0]);    // when I uncomment this line everything works

my_function(my_array);

// my_function gets a wrong val if I comment out the debug print
void my_function(const uint8_t* val){
    Serial0_print_U8(val[0]);              // only prints some_value if I uncomment the print above
}
```

Question what is the proper way to prevent the compiler from ignoring my line. Would volatile work?

Comment: marking the array my_array[] as volatile creates a compiler warning and is ignored. Other solutions besides using the array in a dummy line?

Comment: By turning the compiler optimization level to None (-O0) solves part of the problem but is not an answer to my problem.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve], and state the compiler/version you are using?  Usually this sort of thing is due to undefined behavior elsewhere in the code.

Comment: What do you mean with **reused**?

Comment: I tried to minimize it, but I can't reproduce the problem. Now I suspect that I have a timing problem in a time-critical part that the small delay introduced by the call to the UART function is hiding. Searching elsewhere, thank U.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with "volatile" keyword, I gave up and moved the assignment inside the my_function(), then turned the optimization level to o0, only for the particular function, adding  `__attribute__((optimize("O0")))` to the function declaration, as suggested in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9044490/11006555). It works.

Comment: Your program most definitely has Undefined Behavior. It's the only explanation for the weird behavior (other than the highly unlikely compiler bug). `-O0` might seem to fix the problem but it only hides it ... for now. It might come to bite you a few changes down the line. A seemingly unrelated change in another part of the program will trigger strange behavior again. Or just a compile update or another set of compiler flags. I strongly encourage you to find and fix the bug in the code instead.

Comment: likely culprits for the UB (without seeing the rest of the code): strict aliasing violation or out of bounds access. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98340/what-are-the-common-undefined-unspecified-behavior-for-c-that-you-run-into

Comment: Most probably an SPI timing problem, so in a way you are right. Thank U